# Rainflow counting algorithm

Tags: python, numpy

I've been asked to use a [rainflow counting algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainflow-counting_algorithm) for a project I'm working on.  Does anyone have any experience of libraries that I could use for this task.  I'm already calculating a number of other statistics using Python and Numpy, so any suggestions using / extending these tools would be ideal.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd love to have a good numpy rainflow counting algorithm as well.

Answer (score 8):

I had issues installing WAFO (firewall shenanigans), so I ported a version of a Matlab rainflow counting algorithm in C to Python. It runs the Endo algorithm and also has the option of using a Goodman correction. Only dependency is numpy >= 1.3. Simple, but possibly useful.

Python rainflow function (zip of function and demo script available on [Gist](https://gist.github.com/jennirinker/688a917ccb7a9c14e78f)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Rainflow counting function with Goodman correction
Copyright (C) 2015 Jennifer Rinker
This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
(at your option) any later version.
This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.
You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
Contact: Jennifer Rinker, Duke University
Email:   jennifer.rinker-at-duke.edu
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
USAGE:
To call the function in a script on array of turning points <array_ext>:  
    import rainflow as rf  
    array_out = rf.rainflow(array_ext)
To run the demonstration from a Python console:  
    >>> execfile('demo_rainflow.py')
From the terminal (Windows or UNIX-based):  
    $ python demo_rainflow.py
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DEPENDENCIES:
- Numpy >= v1.3
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTES:
Python code modified from rainflow.c code with mex function for Matlab from 
WISDEM project: https://github.com/WISDEM/AeroelasticSE/tree/master/src/AeroelasticSE/rainflow

Original c code notes:
/*  RAINFLOW $ Revision: 1.1 $ */
/*  by Adam Nieslony, 2009     */
/*  The original code has been modified by Gregory Hayman 2012 as follows: */
/*    abs() has been replaced everywhere with fabs()                       */
/*    the function now applies the Goodman correction to the damage cycle  */
/*      load ranges using a user-supplied fixed load mean, or a fixed load */
/*      mean of zero.                                                      */
/*    the user can supply a the value of a partial damage cycle: uc_mult   */
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"""
from numpy import fabs as fabs
import numpy as np

def rainflow(array_ext,
             flm=0, l_ult=1e16, uc_mult=0.5):
    """ Rainflow counting of a signal's turning points with Goodman correction

        Args:
            array_ext (numpy.ndarray): array of turning points

        Keyword Args:
            flm (float): fixed-load mean [opt, default=0]
            l_ult (float): ultimate load [opt, default=1e16]
            uc_mult (float): partial-load scaling [opt, default=0.5]

        Returns:
            array_out (numpy.ndarray): (5 x n_cycle) array of rainflow values:
                                        1) load range
                                        2) range mean
                                        3) Goodman-adjusted range
                                        4) cycle count
                                        5) Goodman-adjusted range with flm = 0

    """

    flmargin = l_ult - fabs(flm)            # fixed load margin
    tot_num = array_ext.size                # total size of input array
    array_out = np.zeros((5, tot_num-1))    # initialize output array

    pr = 0                                  # index of input array
    po = 0                                  # index of output array
    j = -1                                  # index of temporary array "a"
    a  = np.empty(array_ext.shape)          # temporary array for algorithm

    # loop through each turning point stored in input array
    for i in range(tot_num):

        j += 1                  # increment "a" counter
        a[j] = array_ext[pr]    # put turning point into temporary array
        pr += 1                 # increment input array pointer

        while ((j >= 2) & (fabs( a[j-1] - a[j-2] ) <= \
                fabs( a[j] - a[j-1]) ) ):
            lrange = fabs( a[j-1] - a[j-2] )

            # partial range
            if j == 2:
                mean      = ( a[0] + a[1] ) / 2.
                adj_range = lrange * flmargin / ( l_ult - fabs(mean) )
                adj_zero_mean_range = lrange * l_ult / ( l_ult - fabs(mean) )
                a[0]=a[1]
                a[1]=a[2]
                j=1
                if (lrange > 0):
                    array_out[0,po] = lrange
                    array_out[1,po] = mean
                    array_out[2,po] = adj_range
                    array_out[3,po] = uc_mult
                    array_out[4,po] = adj_zero_mean_range
                    po += 1

            # full range
            else:
                mean      = ( a[j-1] + a[j-2] ) / 2.
                adj_range = lrange * flmargin / ( l_ult - fabs(mean) )
                adj_zero_mean_range = lrange * l_ult / ( l_ult - fabs(mean) )
                a[j-2]=a[j]
                j=j-2
                if (lrange > 0):
                    array_out[0,po] = lrange
                    array_out[1,po] = mean
                    array_out[2,po] = adj_range
                    array_out[3,po] = 1.00
                    array_out[4,po] = adj_zero_mean_range
                    po += 1

    # partial range
    for i in range(j):
        lrange    = fabs( a[i] - a[i+1] );
        mean      = ( a[i] + a[i+1] ) / 2.
        adj_range = lrange * flmargin / ( l_ult - fabs(mean) )
        adj_zero_mean_range = lrange * l_ult / ( l_ult - fabs(mean) )
        if (lrange > 0):
            array_out[0,po] = lrange
            array_out[1,po] = mean
            array_out[2,po] = adj_range
            array_out[3,po] = uc_mult
            array_out[4,po] = adj_zero_mean_range
            po += 1  

    # get rid of unused entries
    array_out = array_out[:,:po]

    return array_out
```

Answer (score 4):

A quick search turned up the following:

WAFO: toolbox for statistical analysis and simulation of random waves and random loads. This includes an implementation of a rainflow counting algorithm

http://code.google.com/p/pywafo/

Comment: This looks really good.  Would Python still require Matlab to use this though?  The Matlab version appears well documented, but I could only find the SVN code for the Python version and it is less obvious how I should use this.

Comment: @dww I don't see matlab dependency for the python version of the toolkit

Comment: The project has moved to github since 2015: https://github.com/wafo-project/pywafo

Answer (score 0):

Fatpack is a package for fatigue analysis of data series with python and numpy.

Extracting rainflow ranges is simple:

```
import fatpack

# Generate a data series
import numpy as np
x = np.random.normal(size=10000)

rainflow_ranges = fatpack.find_rainflow_ranges(x)
```

The package is available on [Github](https://github.com/Gunnstein/fatpack) and [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/fatpack/). Installation is possible through pip, i.e.

```
pip install fatpack
```